# PHP Action File how to

Tags: php

I am working on a project, I want to know if I am doing this correctly.

I have different forms in my project/page and I redirect them to one php file (action.php)
Every form sends its own id so the action.php file knows what to do

Little example:

```
    if($_POST['action'] == "sendmail") {
    //Send mail actions
    }
    if($_POST['action'] == "deleteuser") {
    //Mysql query for deleting the user
    }
```

Like that.

So my question is are there better ways to do this like with a function tag or something like that?

Comment: you'd want to check `isset($_POST['action'])` first and probably want to use `else if` for every condition past the first. This method is fine depending on the needs. If you're learning, then no big deal but to succinctly answer your question: yeah, there are many better ways to do this, but almost always the definition of "better" depends on the needs and the structure. By the time you have enough experience to know the better ways, you won't have to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do this with `switch/case` statements:

```
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'sendmail':
        // send mail actions
        break;
    case 'deleteuser': {
        // delete user actions
        break;
    ...
    default: {
        // Report unrecognized action
}
```

You could further organize this by having the actual action code in separate functions, so it might look like:

```
    case 'sendmail':
        sendmail();
        break;
```